# When function return an struct, it keeps at stack or at heap?

Tags: c

Sample:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Animal{

    char name[100];
    char color[100];

} Animal;

Animal Animal_new() {

    Animal aux;
    return aux;
}

int main() {

    Animal a = Animal_new();    

}
```

The inner struct is created at stack
The returning is a copy that is moved to the heap?
The returning struct must be free?

Comment: The object is copied - there is no "moving to heap".

Comment: There is no requirement for an implementation using a specific memory allocation scheme. It depends on your platform-ABI. Most modern e.g. use registers to pass compound types where appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calling function allocated space on its stack for the return struct by the callee.

Basically since, in your example, main knows it's going to receive a struct Animal it automatically creates space on its stack for it and passes a pointer (this is hidden from you but happens at the assembly level) to this newly created stack space to your Animal_New() function.

This function has its own copy of the struct in its stack space, when returning it copies its value to the caller stack space through the pointer it received.

Asked by @MoLaiSkirulais in the comments:

```
Animal *heapAllocatedAnimal = malloc(sizeof(Animal));
memcpy(heapAllocatedAnimal,&a,sizeof(Animal));
```

As referenced by @Olaf this a "classical" implementation, which should represent most implementations however knowing is better than assuming so when in doubt read the documentation.

Comment: So "Animal a" in main is stored in "stack at main level" right? How can I malloc in heap that "a" that's lives in stack? Is there a best practice? Using memcpy?

Comment: How can you malloc in heap? I don't understand your question. If you wish to create a heap copy of the "a" variable, simply allocate enough space for a Animal struct in the heap and use memcpy to copy the data from a to the pointer returned by the malloc function.                                            Something like Animal *heapAllocatedAnimal = malloc(sizeof(Animal));                                            memcpy(heapAllocatedAnimal,&a,sizeof(Animal));

Comment: C does not enforce a specific allocation for objects. There are implementations which don't use a (classical) stack. It is defined by the ABI. Most modern ABIs return e.g. smaller compound types in registers.

Comment: That is true however, as far as I know (admittedly I'm no expert), most common implementations use this implementation . If you're working/worked on an "uncommon" architecture that uses a different implementation please add the information, I do believe that unless very specific situations my answer is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Functions returning a structure can be implemented by the compiler as taking an extra hidden argument, a pointer to the receiving struct in the caller's scope, possibly a temporary one if the result is not stored.  The function copies its local copy to the destination one.  In your case, both are stored in automatic storage.

If your function had allocated memory from the heap for the structure it returns, the memory would likely become unreachable as the `struct` is returned by value (copied to the destination) and its address, known to the returning function will eventually be lost.

If the structure is small, the compiler can choose to return it in registers as it does for scalar values.

The ABI defines how these matters are handled.  The ABI is system specific, it can be more of less complicated depending on hardware capabilities and implementer's choices.

Answer (score 1):

`struct`s are returned by value. In fact, the only way for anything to get onto the heap is for you to call `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc`.

The local value of `Animal` variable is going to be placed in automatic memory. When the value is returned to `main`, a copy is made from `aux` of `Animal_new` to `a` of `main`. Compilers, however, can optimize things in a way that prevents copying, but one may not assume that this is true.